# Ionic Slide Up Slide Down Animation for only one view in sidebar

Tags: ionic-framework

I have to add slide up and slide down animation for one view for rest of the view I have to continue using slide-left animation , but i tried but I could not find any example of sample , so can anybody point how to customize the animation for only one view

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, that's currently impossible, you can't slide up views vertically.

Though there's another solution you can use this add-on to create similar effect: http://www.idangero.us/swiper/demos/#.VbnLN_mqpBc

It works with Ionic. But there's one problem, you won't be able to scroll view only slider inside.

Another solution is 3rd party Ionic plugin called Swipeable UI cards. Again you're not swiping view only card directive.

Find it here: http://www.gajotres.net/must-have-plugins-for-ionic-framework/2/

There's also a request to implement vertical animation, but you should not expect them in next few months, even year.