# Ionic Navigation Animations

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I've been reading up all over the place looking at documentation and forums trying to find out whether Ionic enables you to specify types of animations when navigating to different screens? So far the only thing I've found is the option to turn animations off completely.

When using an `ion-nav-view` the control basically handles the animation for you going left or right depending where you are in the page stack. Are there options to for instance animate a page in from the bottom? the top? perhaps some type of fade animation?

Comment: Update: In their documentation it states that "More are coming soon" (http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/navTransition/) So, waiting patiently.

Comment: This [link](http://devdactic.com/ionic-with-movejs/) will give options to animate content inside an ionic page.

Comment: Similar question and work around is available in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31716970/ionic-slide-up-slide-down-animation-for-only-one-view-in-sidebar/31717263#31717263)